# Ember.js: Trigger 'Ember.computed.filter' to update when a property changes in the controller

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to filter the contents of an ArrayController using `Ember.computed.filter` based on the input from a text input.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
        filteredPeople: Ember.computed.filter('model',   function(person){
            var searchFilter = this.get('searchFilter');
            var regex = new RegExp(searchFilter, 'i');
            return person.firstName.match(regex);
        }),
        // this is bound to the value of a text input helper
        // I'm just pre-filling the value to show that the filtering does work
        searchFilter: 'kris' 
});
```

This works great and filters as expected.  However, I'd like it to update anytime the value of `searchFilter` is changed (i.e., anytime someone types into the text input).  The problem now is that it only updates if a change is made to the model itself or when the controller first loads.

Is there anyway to trigger `Ember.computed.filter` to update when `searchFilter` updates?  I'm using `Ember.computed.filter` as it seems much more efficient than a normal computed property which I believe will end up recreating the entire array each time (please let me know if I'm mistaken there).  In addition, Ember.compute.filter is just easy to use and very clean!

I created a JSBin with the above setup.  When the user types into the textbox I'd like to somehow trigger the `Ember.computed.filter` to update itself.

> http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pitefica/1/edit

Thank you for your time and any assistance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe too easy, but Ember.computed.filter supports dependent keys using .property() so this will work fine:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
        filteredPeople: Ember.computed.filter('model',   function(person){
            var searchFilter = this.get('searchFilter');
            var regex = new RegExp(searchFilter, 'i');
            return person.firstName.match(regex);
        }).property('model','searchFilter'),
        searchFilter: 'kris' //this is bound to the value of a text input helper
});
```

jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tefes/1/edit

Comment: Not too easy at all!  This is exactly what I was hoping for.  I think I even tried it at some point but must have gotten the syntax off a bit.  Thank you for the JSBin as well.  Always useful to confirm it should work =)

Comment: Glad I could help. The tricky part is that if you only add 'searchFilter' as dependent key it doesn't work. Probably because in some way it overrides the required 'model' dependency key provided by the first parameter of computed.filter(). But that's just a guess, I still need to learn a lot about ember's internals.

Comment: @BavoVanGeit Is the entire array supposed to re-render once the `searchFilter` changes? I was under the impression that `Ember.computed.filer` avoids this by adding/removing items to the same array, but when I inspect the DOM and monitor the individual `li`'s in your jsbin, they definitely seem to all be re-rendered each time.

Comment: I always assumed all the `li`'s needed to be re-render. In the template, a normal each is used that just notices that filteredPeople is changed, hence the {{each}} is re-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you would do this using the `Ember.computed.filter`.
It would be very easy to implement using the `Ember.Array.filter` method and a computed propety:

```
searchFilter: 'kris',

filteredPeople : function(){
    var content = this.get('content'),
        searchFilter = this.get('searchFilter'),
        regex = new RegExp(searchFilter, 'i');

    return content.filter(function(person){
        return person.get('firstName').match(regex);
    });
}.property('content.@each', 'searchFilter')
```

`filteredPeople` will now be re-computed every time something changes in the `content` array or when the `searchFilter` changes value.

JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pitefica/6/edit

Comment: My only concern with this method is that based on looking at the source of Ember.Array.filter it just creates an entirely new array and pushes the new objects onto it that pass the filter criteria.  As a result, I think it will be inefficient for larger arrays.  I'm implementing this for an array that will have 100+ elements and refreshing the entire DOM probably isn't going to perform well.  That's why I was trying to go the Ember.computed.filter route which uses ArrayComputed under the hood.

Comment: Ah ok, that changes things. I actually have experience with rendering 100+ elements into the DOM. I figure you are aware with the ember performance issues on that.
We actually went the following solution: a `pagedContent` array which only shows x amount of items in the `filteredContent` array. This allows for an infinite scrolling or paging implementation.